# Django post save signal calling two times with each request

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.x`

I have a model **TransactionLog** which logs the amount given and updated.
Each time amount is given, a new record is created in **AmountGiven** model and thus will create a log with action as **given** and if the earlier given amount is updated, it will log with action as **updated**.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=AmountGiven)
def amount_given_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        action = 'given'
    else:
        action = 'updated'

    TransactionLog.objects.create(
        user=instance.contact.user,
        contact=instance.contact,
        amount_given=instance,
        amount=instance.amount,
        action=action
    )
```

But even when a new record is created, `post save` receiver is being called two or more than two times. Then, one record is saved as `action=given` in **TransactionLog** and others are creating `action=updated` record in the **TransactionLog** model.

**How can I make it unique to each call?**

Comment: It indicates that you're saving your object twice, is this what you need?

Comment: No, I'm not saving my post twice. I'm making request throw API using Postman.